# Delay function with greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I need a code that when `CheckForZero` happens for the first time, after 30 seconds happens again and it go on every 30 seconds.

```
var waitForZeroInterval = setInterval (CheckForZero, 0);

function CheckForZero ()
{
    if ( (unsafeWindow.seconds == 0)  &&  (unsafeWindow.milisec == 0) )
    {
        clearInterval (waitForZeroInterval);

        var targButton  = document.getElementById ('bottone1799');
        var clickEvent  = document.createEvent ('MouseEvents');

        clickEvent.initEvent ('click', true, true);
        targButton.dispatchEvent (clickEvent);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply track state:

```
var hasRun = false;
function CheckForZero () {
    ... snip ...
    if (!hasRun) {
        hasRun = true;
        setInterval(CheckForZero, 30000);
    }
 }
```

I'd also recommend using setTimeout() rather than setInterval()/clearInterval() (since it doesn't need to be run on a recurring basis).

Edit: I edited the above code to reflect the OP's modified requirements. I've added another version below to simplify, too.

```
setTimeout(CheckForZero, 0); // OR just call CheckForZero() if you don't need to defer until processing is complete
function CheckForZero() {
    ... snip ...
    setTimeout(CheckForZero, 30000);
}
```

Comment: this code works only once... i need that it go on every 30 seconds

Comment: Then replace setTimeout() with setInterval(). Use setTimeout() in your initial call, though, and you can eliminate the cancelInterval() call.

Answer (score 0):

// no need for setInterval because it makes things heavier

```
var d = new Date();
var seconds = d.getSeconds()
var milliseconds = d.getMilliseconds()
var msLeft = 60 * 1000 - seconds * 1000 - milliseconds;
unsafeWindow.setTimeout(doSomething,msLeft)

function doSomething(){
   // your work here

   unsafeWindow.setTimeout(doSomething,30000);
}
```

Comment: I wish there was a way to do it without a helper function (or nested callback). I guess javascript doesn't want you to block.

Comment: @SridharSarnobat check if you can do it using a top-level await